# Existence of mapping class group subgroups isomorphic to the whole group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-group

For a surface $S$, we denote the mapping class group of $S$ as $\operatorname{Map}(S)$.

> **Question:** Are there surfaces $S$ such that there exists some subgroup $H<\operatorname{Map}(S)$ such that $H\cong\operatorname{Map}(S)$?
>
> **Follow up:** If so, are there conditions we can place on $S$ to *always* guarantee such an $H$?

This question has a small partial answer in the affirmative, namely when a surface has a proper subsurface homeomorphic to itself. However, this requires for $S$ to have boundary. Moreover, all examples I have come up with are of infinite-type. **What can we say in the case when $S$ has no boundary, or in the finite-type case?**

Edit: The paper [On injective homomorphisms between Teichmuller modular groups](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs002220050292.pdf) gives a negative answer when $S$ is a closed orientable surface of genus greater than two.

Comment: When $S$ is closed, the mapping class group is coHopfian. This is a result of Ivanov and McCarthy, *On injective homomorphisms between Teichmüller modular groups*.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the reference. I'll add in an edit to note the result.

Comment: Pretty sure braid groups are not cohopfian

Comment: An easy counter example would be annulus...but I need to think for closed surfaces.

Comment: I think Bell and Margalit show that braid groups are not co-hopfian in *Braid groups are almost co-hopfian* -- that's a good point.